# Start UICollectionView at certain index

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview

I'm trying to figure out how to start UICollectionView at a certain index number. By default all cells start at index 0. But let's say I wanted to start at index 2 instead. Any ideas?

Comment: Please can you provide more information about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at UICollecitonView's [scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/scrollToItemAtIndexPath%3aatScrollPosition%3aanimated%3a)

Comment: Unfortunately, depending on how you create your views your UICollectionView may not be setup by viewDidLoad, setting the indexPath is a safer bet in viewWillAppear

Comment: I tried it on iOS 9.3.1, it seems to be safer setting indexPath in viewDidAppear, and the collectionView would still create the indexPath.row = 0 cell first.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you've got a couple of cells that you want to show that aren't in your datasource before showing your datasource. I've done this before.

So when you do cellForRowAtIndexPath (or whatever it is) just change the indexPath row.

So...

numberOfRowsInSection = 2 + your datasource count.

in cellForRow...

if row <= 1 then just use your static content.

else NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = oldIndexPath.section, oldIndexPath.row - 2

I can't access the code at the moment but this is what I guess you're trying to do.